# C# Webservice json data jquery ui with custom formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using asp.net webservice to use it in jQuery UI autocomplete plugin and here is the data I'm getting.

```
{"d":[
    {
        "__type":"WebS.Model.SearchModel",
        "MainCommodityId":1,
        "MainCommodityName":"Pulses",
        "SubcommodityId":3,
        "SubCommodityName":"Urid Dal",
        "BrandId":3,
        "BrandName":"President"
    },
    {
        "__type":"WebS.Model.SearchModel",
        "MainCommodityId":1,
        "MainCommodityName":"Pulses",
        "SubcommodityId":1,
        "SubCommodityName":"Red Gram",
        "BrandId":4,
        "BrandName":"President"
    }
    ]
}
```

This is the script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".input-search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/WebServices/GetAllBrandNames.asmx/getAllBrands',
                data: "{ 'data': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.BrandName,
                            label: item.SubCommodityName
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('error');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('faii');
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            console.log(i.MainCommodityId);
            console.log(i.SubcommodityId);
            console.log(i.BrandId);
        },
        minLength: 1
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + "" + item.BrandName + " in " + item.MainCommodityName + " - " + item.SubCommodityName + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

The issues are:

1. When I tried to enter keyword say: **pre** the aforesaid output is coming in json. However, the list is returning only one "President" item where it should display 2 items.
2. The list is displaying "undefined in undefined - undefined" instead of values after adding `.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem` function.
3. `console.log`s are also undefined after selecting an item.

How can these issues fixed?

Comment: have you try var data=JSON.parse(data) as first line in success in $.ajax?

Comment: Yes. I've tried that also.

Comment: if data is able to encoded then may be some problem with returning json try to create one global json object`s array and push json object into that array and return it.

Comment: I can see the two "President" coming on your test site. Just your navbar is hiding it. About undefined. you can try adding the select event after appending the `<li>` items by using `$( ".input-search" ).on( "selectmenuselect", function( event, ui ) {do something..} );`

Comment: So it was to prevent the default action on `focus` and `select` and use `_renderItem` for custom dropdown , other than this I guess everything was right. Nice (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to achieve what I wanted. Answering my question as it may helpful to someone.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".input-search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/WebServices/GetAllBrandNames.asmx/getAllBrands',
                data: "{ 'data': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
              // don't forget to $.map to (data.d where d is the top node
                        return {
             // assign values from json response for further use
                            brandid: item.BrandId,
                            brand: item.BrandName,
                            maincommodityid: item.MainCommodityId,
                            maincommodity: item.MainCommodityName,
                            subcommodityid: item.SubcommodityId,
                            subcommodity: item.SubCommodityName
                        }
                    }));
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('Server Error. Please try again.');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('Failed to get result');
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
            event.preventDefault();
            // do further action here such as assigning id to hidden field etc. 
            $(".input-search").val(ui.item.brand);
            // navigate to the selected item's url ex: /catalogue/1/1/pulses/red-gram/4/president
            var str = "/catalogue/" + ui.item.maincommodityid + "/" +
                 ui.item.subcommodityid + "/" + $.trim(ui.item.maincommodity.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()) + "/" +
                 $.trim(ui.item.subcommodity.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()) + "/" + ui.item.brandid + "/" +
                  $.trim(ui.item.brand.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase());
            window.location = str;
        },
        minLength: 3
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        // get values and create custom display
        var $a = $("<a></a>");                  
        $("<strong></strong>").text(item.brand).appendTo($a);
        $("<span></span>").text(" in ").appendTo($a);
        $("<span></span>").text(item.subcommodity).appendTo($a);
        return $("<li></li>").append($a).appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
    ul.ui-front {
        z-index: 1200; // change z-index according to your UI.
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The default behavior of the select event is to update the input with ui.item.value. This code runs after your event handler.

Simply prevent the default action on `select` and `focus` using `event.preventDefault()` or by `return false` and use `_renderItem` for custom dropdown.

```
focus: function(event, ui) {
   // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
   event.preventDefault(); // or return false;
}

select: function(event, ui) {
   // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
   event.preventDefault(); 
   //do something
}
```

**References:**

1. [jQuery UI Autocomplete Examples](http://salman-w.blogspot.in/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html)
2. [Example 2](http://biasecurities.com/2010/04/have-jquery-autocomplete-behave-like-google-suggest/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do this way and Its work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var jsondata=array();
$.post("/WebServices/GetAllBrandNames.asmx/getAllBrands",{data: request.term},function(data){
var data=JSON.parse(data);
$.each(data.d, function( index, value ) {
  jsondata[index].value=value;
 });
$(".input-search").autocomplete({
    source:jsondata,
    //other property and events
 })
});
```

I mean apply source JSON after completing request because sometimes if AJAX takes some time to load execution pointer still execute rest of code without waiting for response.

I did not test this code but I always do this way and never get your kind of error. Good Luck

Comment: No  this is not working. Throwing error at: `{ 'data': '" + request.term`